# Можно ли делать обертку вокруг HANDLE копируемой? С++

Tags: c++, winapi

Хочу сделать класс Process, который будет ООП-оберткой вокруг `HANDLE` процесса. И мне стало интересно как сделать такой класс копируемым. Ведь в деструкторе данный процесс должен уничтожать хэндл через `CloseHandle`, если мы скопируем такой класс вместе с хэндлом, потом один класс уничтожится, то во втором классе хэндл станет невалидным.
Отсюда вопрос: можно ли просто взять и сделать такую обертку копируемой? Если нет, то насколько правильным будет использование `std::shared_ptr` с делитером ввиде `CloseHandle`?

Минимальный пример моей обертки:

```
  class CMDProcess
  {
  public:
    CMDProcess() noexcept;
    CMDProcess(const CMDProcess &) = default;
    CMDProcess(CMDProcess &&) = default;
    CMDProcess& operator=(const CMDProcess &) = default;
    CMDProcess& operator=(CMDProcess &&) = default;
    ~CMDProcess() noexcept;

    void CloseProcess() noexcept;
    std::optional<DWORD> GetExitCode() const noexcept;
    bool OpenProcess(std::string commandLine) noexcept;
    void WaitForOutput() noexcept;

  private:
    PROCESS_INFORMATION m_procInfo;
    STARTUPINFO m_startInfo;
    HANDLE m_process;
    bool m_isOpen;
  };
```

Comment: В winapi есть функция `DuplicateHandle`, можно реализовать свой конструктор и оператор копирования с её использованием, и в деструкторе и операторе копирования вызывать `CloseHandle`. Проще создать один `shared_ptr<HANDLE >`, передавая ему custom deleter , вызывающий `CloseHandle`, но не уверен, какой вариант лучше - `shared_ptr` работает на атомарных операциях и копируется быстро, на счет системных функций не знаю, нужно читать документацию.

Comment: @Ariox меня смущает также то, что в доке по `shared_ptr` сказано, что делитер должен не кидать исключений. А CloseHandle делает это в дебаг моде для невалидных хэндлов

Comment: @Ariox а также, что придется делать обертку и вокруг  STARTUPINFO и PROCESS_INFORMATION, ибо они также хранят хэндлы, которые просто так не скопируешь

Comment: CloseHandle не кидает никаких исключений. Передача в него невалидного дескриптора всегда является признаком того, что программа находится в несогласованном состоянии. А процесс нельзя сделать копируемым, так как при копировании дескриптора нельзя будет копировать сам процесс.

Comment: @user7860670 Понял, но с утверждением про исключения не согласен, цитата с доки: `If the application is running under a debugger, the function will throw an exception if it receives either a handle value that is not valid or a pseudo-handle value.`

Comment: Там не идет речь о С++ исключениях. Собственно CloseHandle - это С API, оно в принципе не бросает С++ исключения

Comment: Деструктор в любом случае не должен бросать исключений, это нарушит логику программы в целом, и начиная с C++11 деструкторы неявно помечены как noexcept , и могут бросать исключения только если явно помечены noexcept(false). Если исключение возможно только при невалидном дескрипторе - вы должны обернуть функцию в `try{ CloseHandle(handle )} catch(...) {/*ignore*/}` предполагая, что дескриптор валиден . Если вы этого не сделаете, компилятор автоматически обернет это в конструкцию ` try{ CloseHandle(handle )} catch(...) { terminate(); }`. Теоретически проблему можно обойти различными хаками.

Comment: Что касается STARTUPINFO и PROCESS_INFORMATION, если у вас составной объект - просто создайте `shared_ptr<CMDProcess>` . Или создайте класс, инкапсулирующий `shared_ptr<CMDProcess>`. `CMDProcess` не будет копируемым  (нужно явно запретить конструктор копирования), но пользователь не будет видеть `CMDProcess`, он будет видеть копируемую обертку над shared_ptr